# | character is not allowed for attribute href on element link

Tags: html, validation

I have a link element in .html file:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora|Merriweather:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I throw it in https://validator.w3.org/, it displays this error:

> Bad value [https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora|Merriweather:300,400](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora%7CMerriweather:300,400) for attribute href on element link: Illegal character in query: | is not allowed.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display non-standard letters and characters in browsers and plug-ins you need to use hexadecimal values. In your case instead of | you need to use %7C.

```
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Lora%7CMerriweather:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
```

You can check more [here](https://www.eso.org/%7Endelmott/url_encode.html)

Answer (score 2):

UrlEncode the offending `|` which ends up as `%7C`

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora%7CMerriweather:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
```